# How do I get a StatelessSession when using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, lagom

I am trying to get a StatelessSession using SessionFactory with the following code:

```
final Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
final SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
final StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

but when I test the code it fails with the following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.transport.TransportException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.preInsertInMemoryValueGeneration(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3696)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3673)
at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:87)
at z.c.e.z.b.r.JPABatchRepository.lambda$null$0(JPABatchRepository.java:49)
at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:142)
at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:100)
at z.c.e.z.b.r.JPABatchRepository.wrap(JPABatchRepository.java:42)
at z.c.e.z.b.r.JPABatchRepository.lambda$createBatch$1(JPABatchRepository.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have followed this tutorial [Working with stateless session in hibernate and jpa](http://ufasoli.blogspot.com/2017/10/working-with-stateless-session-in.html) but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am using Lagom Framework and Hibernate 5.3.7.Final. I have also followed the tutorial on [Hibernate 5.3.7.Final](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) but to no avail.

Someone mentioned on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314766/statelesssession-being-cast-to-session-in-abstractentitypersister-hibernate)  that it was a bug which was supposed to be fixed on 5.2.2, but I am using 5.3.7.Final and still getting the error.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error? Or a proper way to get an Instance of StatelessSession in Hibernate?

Comment: Hi, Do you found the solution ?, If yes can you explain it

Answer (score 0):

According to that error message, the session is already a `StatelessSession`, so you should be able to unwrap it directly as one:

```
final StatelessSession session = entityManager.unwrap(StatelessSession.class);
```

Comment: If I do that I get: PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface org.hibernate.StatelessSession